# Вызов tooltip в bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Подскажите почему не работает tooltip?

```
<input id="name-send" name="name"  class="input-people" placeholder="ВАШЕ ИМЯ" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="• поле Имя обязательно для заполнения• длина имени должна составлять не менее двух символов • поле должно содержать только русские или латинские буквы"><br>

if($("#name-send").hasClass('error'))
{
   $('#name-send').css('border','1.5px solid red').tooltip('show');
}else{
   $('#name-send').css('border','1.5px solid green');
}
```

Comment: Как-то странно у Вас скрипт объявлен, посреди html-кода. Надеюсь, это для примера? Если да, то запостите его отдельно и полностью.

Comment: Там слишком много кода, потому полностью не выложу( Суть, в том, что нужно показывать tooltip исходя из условия

Comment: как именно не работает? показывает ошибку в консоли? ничего не делает? делает что-то не то, что ожидалось? заходите ли вы в условие `if($("#name-send").hasClass('error'))`? возможно в момент вызова у инпута просто нет класса _error_

Answer (score 1):

Зависит также от версии бутстрапа, например в 4  нужен файл tether.js
Проверьте в консоли нет ли ошибок